# Elasticsearch: conditionally sort on 2 fields, 1 replaces the other if it exists

Tags: ruby, sorting, elasticsearch

Without scripting, I need to sort records based on rating. The system-rating exists for all records, but a user-rating may or may not exist. If a user-rating does exist I want to use that value in the sort instead of the system-rating, for that particular record and only for that record.

Tried looking into the `missing` setting but it only allows `_first`, `_last` or a custom value (that will be used for missing docs as the sort value):

```
{
    "sort" : [
        { "user_rating" : {"missing" : "_last"} },
    ],
    "query" : {
        "term" : { "meal" : "cabbage" }
    }
}
```

...but is there a way to specify the custom value should be `system_rating` when `user_rating` is missing?

I can do the following:

```
query_hash[:sort] = []
if user_rating.exist?
  query_hash[:sort] << {
    "user_rating" => {
      "order": sort_direction,
      "unmapped_type": "long",
      "missing": "_last",
    }
  }
end
query_hash[:sort] << {
  "system_rating" => {
    "order": sort_direction,
    "unmapped_type": "long",
  }
}
```

...but that will always sort user rated records on top regardless of the `user_rating` value.

I know that scripting will allow me to do it but we cannot use scripting. Is it possible?

Comment: Scripting or build a custom field **at indexing time** that will contain the already built value for sorting.

Comment: Sadly, @andrei-stefan, I believe you are correct. Add your comment as an answer below and I'll accept it after a day or 2 if no other answer comes along.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way is scripting or building a custom field at indexing time that will contain the already built value for sorting.